# Get most common day of week for column in Postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I want to see the most common day of the week that widgets get `created_at` on my Postgres database.

This is as far as I've got, but it returns me an average (3.744...) rather than  an integer representing the *most common* day of the week. Does anyone know how I could improve this?

```
SELECT AVG(start_day) AS start_day
FROM (SELECT date_part('dow', created_at) AS start_day
      FROM widgets) TMP;
```

Comment: Group by date_part, and order by count (descending)? (I know what the LINQ would be in C#, but I wouldn't like to assume I could get the SQL right...)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date_part('dow', created_at) AS start_day
  FROM widgets
 GROUP BY date_part('dow', created_at)
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT start_day, count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT date_part('dow', created_at) AS start_day
  FROM widgets) sub
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I questioned why you chose to use a subquery, but I see that you avoid duplication of the calculation of day-of-week.

Comment: @KenGeis Using an identical function call twice in a single query does not mean that it gets evaluated twice, the query planner is smarter than that. Using the sub-query yields code that is easier to understand IMHO, the query plan of both our answers is _exactly_ same: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/22bcb/3. Your earlier solution - minus the obvious errors - is somewhat slower but very comparable.

Comment: Yes, I should have said that you avoid duplicating the declaration of the day-of-week expression.